# How to immediately submit any pending non-fatal Crashlytics logs

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

According to the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html?caught%20exceptions#caught-exceptions):

> To reduce your users’ network traffic, Crashlytics batches logged
>   exceptions together and sends them the next time the app launches.

I would like to a trigger a log submission immediately as a result of a user problem report.  I cannot know if or when a user will start the app again.  Is it possible to force fabric to submit any pending reports?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Fabric - send Caught Exceptions at custom interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347211/android-fabric-send-caught-exceptions-at-custom-interval)

Comment: How this service is usable for commercial applications with this limitation is beyond me. Disgrace.